# How to round up decimal values in jolt?

Tags: transformation, jolt

I have the input as below,

INPUT:

```
{
   "value": 265.3
}
```

I want to remove the decimal values.

OUTPUT:

```
{
   "value": 265
}
```

JOLT:

```
[{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
     "value": "=toLong"
  }
}]
```

This works fine for removing decimals but not for rounding up like,

```
268.1  --->  268

268.9  --->  269
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for the aforementioned scenario?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by `rounding` and then converting to `int`:

**Input Json:**

```json
{
  "value1": 268.1,
  "value2": 268.9
}
```

**Jolt spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=divideAndRound(0,@(0),1)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toInteger"
    }
  }
]
```

**Result:**

```json
{
  "value1" : 268,
  "value2" : 269
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not OOTB support for that in Jolt.